# Child MovieClip is triggering events with mouseChildren and mouseEnabled set to false

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have thumbnails loaded into a container. Each thumb has a MOUSE_OVER and _OUT listener. I have each thumbs mouseChildren set to false.

The popup that gets created behind the thumb is triggering the MOUSE_OVER events. I have mouseEnabled set to false on the popup.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I'd appreciate any clues.

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < numOfThumbs; i++) {

    // add thumb
    thumb = new Thumb
    thumb.buttonMode = true;
    thumb.mouseChildren = false;
    container.addChild(thumb);

    // add listener
    thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, rollOverHandler, false, 0, true);
    thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, rollOutHandler, false, 0, true);

    // add popup
    popup = new Popup;
    popup.mouseEnabled = false;
    thumb.addChildAt(popup, 0);
}

private function rollOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Hey popup.... stop triggering this. I just want the thumb to trigger this. jerk.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as expected.  Child objects affect the bounds of the parent (which is what is recieving the mouseOver/Out).

Your best bet is to either:

A:  Put your popup in a different displayObject container (not as a child of thumb)

B: temporarily disable mouseInput on the Thumb while the popup is visible,

C:   on the popup, set mouseEnabled = true (keep mouseChildren=false) and check in your rollOverHandler if the event target (e.target) is the popup and return if true:

```
if(e.target == popup) return;
```

Answer (score -2):

Set `mouseChildren` to false for the main MovieClip.